# How can i host the matterport 3D tour archives to my website and make it viewable?

Tags: deployment, shopify, matterport

[the archives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixFEU.png) How can i host these Matterport archives in a web server to be viewable? I am trying to add one virtual tour to a shopify page and i am stuck. I found a way to upload the archive through ftp to the hostgator account in the public_html folder.(using filezilla) I get a 404 error when i try to access the index.html in the matterport archive folder through the domain. I'm new to this, can someone point me to the right direction to make it work on a hosted web server or make the matterport archives work online so i can refer to it as a link to the shopify page?

Answer (score 0):

I just signed up to answer you :)
Matterport is a SaaS company their VR tours won't work without their software.
So you have one of the following 3 options:

- Take your 360 photos and make the tour manually in another software, LIKE https://kuula.co
- If you want to host Matterport in your web server to cut the fees, I'm sorry to inform you that's not the case, you will need a Business subscription, a paid API key, and a partnership in order to be able to do so, it will be much cheaper to just imbed the tour in your webpage and keep it hosted in Matterport.
- I will advise you to publish the tour on Google and then embed the link in your website since Google Street View supports VR tours and you can do this on Matterport website, there will be an additional cost but the tour will be hosted for free.